# Checkbox list inside datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkbox list inside a datalist:

```
     <asp:DataList ID="dtlstfilter" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <div style="display: none;" id='<%#changes(Eval("FilterCode")) %>' class="p7ABcontent">
       <p>
        <asp:CheckBoxList AutoPostBack="true" Font-Size="12px" ID="chklist" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
        </p>
        </div>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:DataList>
```

And I loaded two list items in this to say 'yes' and 'no'. How can i get the event in the selected checkbox?

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind SelectedIndexChanged event and pass the arguments to get the current rowNumber or anything else you need using custom attributes (user defined attributes).

**In html**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlstfilter" runat="server"  >
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div style="display: none;" id='<%#changes(Eval("FilterCode")) %>' class="p7ABcontent">
         <p>
             <asp:CheckBoxList AutoPostBack="true" Font-Size="12px" ID="chklist" runat="server"  onselectedindexchanged="chklist_SelectedIndexChanged"   CommandName="myCommand" CommandArguments="1" DataListRowNumber="1" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
        </p>
     </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**In Code behind**

```
protected void chklist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList chklst = (CheckBoxList)sender;
    string commandName = chklst.Attributes["CommandName"].ToString();
    string commandArguments = chklst.Attributes["commandArguments"].ToString();
    string dataListRowNumber = chklst.Attributes["DataListRowNumber"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: checkboxlist doesnt have selectedindexchanged event

Comment: There was a typing mistake in event name check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, just to think about. This solution minimizes the roundtrips between client and server.

Use a button's click event. You can iterate through the DataListItems and use the FindControl method to find the CheckBoxList. Now you can determine which elements are checked:

```
foreach (DataListItem item in dtlstfilter.Items)
{
  if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
  {
    CheckBoxList checkBox = item.FindControl("chklist") as CheckBoxList;
  }
}
```